# What does the term 'User Specific' Objects mean?

Tags: asp.net

What is the term 'User Specific' Objects mean when initializing them for a user connects to your web application for the first time?

regards
Fri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that each user would get their own instance of an object.  A Session object comes to mind, something that is accessible to one particular user and no others.  It's common for storing authorization data.